# How to use unicode escape sequence with variables?

Tags: java, unicode, compiler-errors, unicode-escapes

This is the code I currently have to concatenate a then b then c and so on in a loop (scanned number of times) using java:

```
public String toString()
{
  String answers = "";
  int numChoices = choices.length;
  char letter;
  String result;
  int letterNum = 0061;
  while (numChoices > 0)
  {
     letter = "\u" + letterNum;
     result  = letter + ") " + choices[choices.length-numChoices] + "\n";
     answers += result;
     numChoices --;
     letterNum ++;
  }

  return question + "\n" + answers;
}
```

I thought unicode escape sequences would be my best option, but it didn't work the way I tried so I'm obviously doing something wrong.  How do I fix this?

The error I'm getting is:

```
MultChoice.java:40: illegal unicode escape
     letter = "\u" + letterNum;
```

Comment: 0061 is 49 which is ASCII for "1" and you seem to enumerate choices, why would you need escaping at all? Just use normal values 1, 2, 3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode escapes are processed by javac, *very* early in compilation, before parsing. The compiler never sees Unicode escapes, only code points. Therefore you can't use them at runtime. Instead, try this:

```
public String toString()
{
  String answers = "";
  int numChoices = choices.length;
  char letter = 'a';
  String result;
  while (numChoices > 0)
  {
     result  = "" + letter + ") " + choices[choices.length-numChoices] + "\n";
     answers += result;
     numChoices --;
     letter ++;
  }

  return question + "\n" + answers;
}
```

A `char` is just an unsigned 16-bit integer, so you can do all the normal integer things with it, like increment. There's no need for a separate `int`--`'a'` and `(char) 0x61` are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had no idea this could work.

Comment: Now make it work with all Unicode code points, not merely the BMP.

Comment: Dealing with supplementary planes in Java is a pain. It's also out of scope for this question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `letterNum` is 49 (61 in octal), so it turns into `"\u49"`, which is not valid.

You possibly were supposed to use `0x0061`, and then turn it to a `String` using `Integer.toHexString(letterNum)`.

Edit: It seems that you can't create a `String` using `"\u" + something`.

So, a possible way is `Character.toString((char) letterNum)`.